# Why isn't my command outputting to NodeJS typical stdout?

Tags: node.js, linux, shell, stdout

I have a command `ascp` that, if I run in the terminal, will output the progress of the command (it's downloading content from the cloud and spits out transfer speed, completion, etc.)

However, when I run it using `child_process.exec` command, it doesn't log anything to the console.

I believe that `ascp` is sending output in a different manner than most commands. It is provided by IBM Aspera, and they have another command `aspera ats download` that is sending out data in a proper manner when I use `child_process.exec`.

This is my code:

```
let command="ascp ${args}"
const child = exec(command, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.log('err: ' + err)
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout)
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr)
})
```

I've tried using `script` as mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70895/output-of-command-not-in-stderr-nor-stdout) but I cannot seem to get that to spit out the output either.

Comment: Some programs check whether their output is connected to a terminal. If it's not, they don't show interactive messages like progress indicators.

Comment: @Barmar Interesting... Any ways around this?

Comment: If you have `Expect`, it includes a tool that can be used to run programs with their output connected to a pseudo-tty.